# How to detect DoubleClick in WPF ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

In my WPF application I have Toggle Button, I want to detect when user double click on it (in both cases if it checked or unchecked).

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Control.MouseDoubleClick?` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PreviewMouseDoubleClick` event ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.previewmousedoubleclick%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

XAML:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="tButton" Height="30" Content="MyButton"                      
              PreviewMouseDoubleClick="tButton_PreviewMouseDoubleClick"
            />
```

Code-behind:

```
private void tButton_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    tButton.IsChecked = !tButton.IsChecked.Value;
    e.Handled = true;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I can force double click on check, I have 3 cases, Checked, Unchecked, Double Click, If i double click on the button when it's checked it shouldn't unchecked the button, should force double click. Is that possible?

Comment: @AbdusalamElsherif check my answer again :)

Comment: You are awesome, It works, but In my case Check mean button background image is green, unchecked is yellow, when I pressed double click on checked(green) it flashing to yellow then back to green. Is any idea to avoid this flashing, any way I thank you very much to helping me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick` event

xaml:

```
   <ToggleButton Height="75" Width="100" PreviewMouseDoubleClick="Control_OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick"/>
```

code-behind:

```
private void Control_OnPreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var toggleButtton = sender as ToggleButton;
    if (toggleButtton != null)
    {
        if (toggleButtton.IsChecked.HasValue)
        {
            if (toggleButtton.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                // Checked
            }
            else
            {
                // Unchecked

                // this will re-check the button if double-click unchecks it
                //
                toggleButtton.IsChecked = true;
                toggleButtton.Focus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I can force double click on check, I have 3 cases, Checked, Unchecked, Double Click, If i double click on the button when it's checked it shouldn't unchecked the button, should force double click. Is that possible?

Comment: So do you not want it to uncheck if it is double-clicked? you can simply just set it to true again if double-clicked.

Answer (score 1):

This event is pretty easy with togglebuttons
Xaml you write the following to get an EventHandler:

```
<ToggleButton Name="button1" MouseDoubleClick="button1_DoubleClick" />
```

In c# you write the following to get an EventHandler:

```
button1.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(button1_DoubleClick);
```

And in both cases you need:

```
void button1_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how I can force double click on check, I have 3 cases, Checked, Unchecked, Double Click, If i double click on the button when it's checked it shouldn't unchecked the button, should force double click. Is that possible?

Comment: The only way I can Think of: Its not good but it might work...
Transparent rectangle over the togglebutton. Get the events from the rectangle and Start a timer on click, end timer on double click. If timer passes 500ms then Check the toggle button.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx